# openacc error when assigning values to dynamically allocated struct member array of struct referenced by pointer

Tags: c, struct, gpgpu, openacc, pgcc

I am trying to wrap my head around combining openacc with pointers to structs containing dynamically allocated members. The code below fails with

> Failing in Thread:1
> call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution

when compiled using nvc ("nvc 20.9-0 LLVM 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp haswell"). As far as I can tell I am following the approach suggested eg in the OpenACC 'getting started' guide. But somehow presumably the pointers don't stick (?) on the device. Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct grid
{
  int N;
  double *X;
} grid;

void allocate(grid* g, int N)
{
  g->N = N;
  g->X = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * g->N);

  #pragma acc enter data create(g[0:1])
  #pragma acc enter data create(g->X[0:N])
}

void release(grid* g)
{
  #pragma acc exit data delete(g->X[0:g->N])
  #pragma acc exit data delete(g[0:1])

  free(g->X);
}

void fill(grid * g)
{
  int i;

  #pragma acc parallel loop
  for (i = 0; i < g->N; i++)
  {
    g->X[i] = 42; // the cuprit, commenting this removes the error too
  }
}

int main()
{
  grid g;

  allocate(&g, 10);

  fill(&g);

  release(&g);

  return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the compiler feedback messages you'll see something like:

```
     fill:
          32, Accelerator restriction: size of the GPU copy of g is unknown
              Generating Tesla code
              32, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
          32, Generating implicit copyin(g) [if not already present]
          37, Generating update self(g->X[:g->N])
```

The problem being that the compiler can't implicitly copy aggregate types with dynamic data members so you need to add a "present(g)" to indicate that g is already the device.

Also, you'll want to copyin g in order to get the value of N on the device and no need to include the array shape in the exit data delete directive.  For example:

```
% cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct grid
{
  int N;
  double *X;
} grid;

void allocate(grid* g, int N)
{
  g->N = N;
  g->X = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * g->N);

  #pragma acc enter data copyin(g[0:1])
  #pragma acc enter data create(g->X[0:N])
}

void release(grid* g)
{
  #pragma acc exit data delete(g->X)
  #pragma acc exit data delete(g)

  free(g->X);
}

void fill(grid * g)
{
  int i;

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(g)
  for (i = 0; i < g->N; i++)
  {
    g->X[i] = 42; // the cuprit, commenting this removes the error too
  }
  #pragma acc update self(g->X[:g->N])
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("%d : %f \n",i,g->X[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  grid g;

  allocate(&g, 10);

  fill(&g);

  release(&g);

  return 0;
}

% nvc -acc test.c -Minfo=accel -V20.9 ; a.out
allocate:
     17, Generating enter data copyin(g[:1])
         Generating enter data create(g->X[:N])
release:
     24, Generating exit data delete(g[:1],g->X[:1])
fill:
     32, Generating present(g[:1])
         Generating Tesla code
         32, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
     37, Generating update self(g->X[:g->N])
0 : 42.000000
1 : 42.000000
2 : 42.000000
3 : 42.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. The lack of an update self statement and the use of create rather than copyin were casualties of quickly setting up a minimal demonstration of the issue (the latter shouldn't have been), and it was the 'present' part that was the piece of the puzzle that I was really missing here.